# Cannot Create QEMU Socket Networking in Windows Host using Multicast Fails with Unknown Error

Tags: windows, networking, socket, qemu, multicast

I am trying to create a simulated VLAN using socket networking, and the only way to connect multiple VMs in one network in QEMU using socket networking is by using the multicast `mcast` option of the `socket` network backend, to create a shared BUS.

However, when I try to use the following arguments in QEMU to create a multicast socket network:

`-device e1000,netdev=sock-0 -netdev id=sock-0,mcast=230.0.0.1:1234`

it fails with:

`can't bind ip=230.0.0.1 to socket: Unknown error` in my Windows host.

Is this is a QEMU bug, or am I missing a prerequisite before running the QEMU command (such as expecting a multicast listener running, ...etc.)?

By the way, I am using Windows 10, and running a cross-compiled QEMU 4.2.0. I printed the error right before the failure on bind in `net/socket.c` of the QEMU source code in line 256, and `WSAGetLastError` returns `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, QEMU 4.2.0 has a bug with socket networking using multicast. It does not use `INADDR_ANY` (or `0.0.0.0`) for the listening socket, but rather the multicast group address passed-in by the user. To fix this issue, I changed the following source code lines in `net/socket.c` (from 256 to 261, inclusive):

```
   ret = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)mcastaddr, sizeof(*mcastaddr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        error_setg_errno(errp, errno, "can't bind ip=%s to socket",
                         inet_ntoa(mcastaddr->sin_addr));
        goto fail;
    }
```

to

```
    struct in_addr group_addr = mcastaddr->sin_addr;
    if (localaddr) {
        mcastaddr->sin_addr = *localaddr;
    } else {
        mcastaddr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    }
    ret = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)mcastaddr, sizeof(*mcastaddr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        error_setg_errno(errp, errno, "can't bind ip=%s to socket",
                         inet_ntoa(mcastaddr->sin_addr));
        goto fail;
    }
    mcastaddr->sin_addr = group_addr;
```

where I would preserve the group's address in a variable, set the socket address to either `INADDR_ANY` or a user-passed-in local address, create the listening socket, and then revert to the group's address so I can join the group later on. The solution works in Windows built binaries, but I believe it would work on other operating systems as well.